# В чем может быть причина негативных значений loss в модели Sequential?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

День добрый. Вопрос такой: создаю модель для бинарной цели (1/0) вида

```
 def get_model():

      model = Sequential()
      model.add(Dense(8,input_shape=(24,),activation='relu'))
      model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
      model.add(Dense(8,activation='sigmoid'))
      model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

      model.compile(
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adam'
      )

      return model

 model = get_model()
```

Но при обучении модель выдает такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Код обучения модели:

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience = 3)

model = get_model()

history = model.fit(
  X_train, y_train,
  validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
  epochs = 50,
  callbacks = [early_stopping]
)
```

Пример данных до нормализации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после нормализации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете привести воспроизводимый пример данных и код, где вы обучаете модель?

Comment: А что у вас в y_train, y_test, интересно? А то тут намекают, что такое может быть, если там не 0/1, а что-то другое: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264649/keras-binary-crossentropy-has-negative-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже отметил [CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260769/crazyelf), следовало внимательно проверить данные в y_train, y_test. В моем случае там было несколько цифр, отличных от 1/0. После удаления этих данных проблема решилась.